# Injecting field with annotation @Inject returns null

Tags: java, cdi, inject, weld

I'm trying to get into Weld and cdi-api. I have created a empty beans.xml (with bean-discovery-mode="all") and I defined classes like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
        container.select(MainWindow.class).get();
```

```
@Dependent
public class MainWindow{
  ...
  //some swing components
  ...
  private void initItemTableView() {
     itemTableModel = new ItemTableModel();
```

I heard that you can't use keyword 'new' because CDI will not have control over lifecycle of the object so instead, I also tried injecting *ItemTableModel* by **@Inject** and defining it as **@ApplicationScoped** but with the same results.

```
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class ItemTableModel extends AbstractModel {
    
        @Inject
        private TtcDataService ttcDataService; // <- this is null
```

(TtcDataService is defined with **@ApplicationScoped** annotation)

I'm complete newbie in terms of CDI, I would be very grateful for pointing out where I did wrong.

Comment: You're using CDI and `@Inject`, but the underlying problem is identical. tl;dr use constructor injection and the problem usually never has the opportunity to arise.